# Prism module load as window

Tags: c#, prism

Is it possible load module with Prism and Unity bootstrapper as a window instead like a view?

File Bootstrapper.cs

```
class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        var zeroModule = typeof(ZeroModule);
        ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo()
        {
            ModuleName = zeroModule.Name,
            ModuleType = zeroModule.AssemblyQualifiedName,
            InitializationMode = InitializationMode.OnDemand
        });
    }

}
```

in File View/MainWindow.cs

```
_moduleManager.LoadModule("ZeroModule");
```

File ZeroModule.cs

```
public class ZeroModule : IModule
    {
        IRegionManager _regionManager;
        public ZeroModule(RegionManager regionManager)
        {
            _regionManager = regionManager;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(MainView));
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far to accomplish this?

Comment: It sure is, why don't you just spin up a new window, and register the view with a region in that new window?

Comment: @MichaelL. I tried to do it by my self with google and some examples, but without success :/

Comment: @Clint Thank you very much this is enough for my purposes

Comment: @LaadisHloušek Understood, but showing us what you've tried is part of how we do things around here. It helps us to help you more easily. Also, it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question! If you've found a solution, please create an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @LaadisHloušek no problem, I'm not sure if there's a "proper" way to do it, but that's certainly how I remember doing it when I worked with Prism.

Comment: Quite sure it is impossible to _load a module_ as either view or window. But your module could create a new window and put a view in there.